# How to edit Records using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, edit

how do i edit my records?i keep getting to wrong pages.. thanks in advance really need help
i based my code in my delete function i got from yesterday but i have no luck doing so in edit
controller

```
    function update()
{
    $booking=array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'nationality'=>$this->input->post('nationality'),
        'number_of_guest'=>$this->input->post('number_of_guest'),
        'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),
        'package'=>$this->input->post('package'),
        'request'=>$this->input->post('request')
        );

    $this->site_model->update_record($booking);
    $this->edit();
}
```

site_model

```
      function update_record($booking)
{
    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->update('booking', $booking);
}
```

edit.php

```
      <div id="bgbp"></div>
<div id="bp">
    <h2 class="nb">Update</h2>
    <?php echo form_open('site/update');?>
    <div id="nems">
        <p>
            <label for="name"> Guest name(s): </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name(s)"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="nat">
        <p>
            <label for="nationality">Nationality: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nationality" id="nationality" placeholder="Nationality"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="nog">
        <p>
            <label for="number_of_guest"> Number of Guest:</label>
            <input type="number" name="number_of_guest" id="number_of_guest" placeholder="Number of Guest"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="doa">  
        <p>
            <label for="date"> Date of Arrival:</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainselection">

        <select name="package" id="input7">
            <option value="" style="display:none">Choose Package to avail</option>
            <option value="Package A. Half - day City Tour">Package A. Half - day City Tour</option>
            ...
            <option value="Package B. Honda Bay Island Hopping">Package B. Honda Bay Island Hopping</option>
            <option value="Package C. St. Paul's Subterranean River National Park or Underground River">Package C. St. Paul's Subterranean River National Park or Underground River</option>                              
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="or">
        <p>
            <label for="request"> Other Request: </label>
            <input type="comment" name="request" id="request" placeholder="Other Request"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="sub">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="msg()" />
        </p>
</div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

my view page..(whre my edit and delete button show)

```
       <?php 
   $this->table->set_heading("Name","Nationality","Number of Guest","Date of Arrival","Package","Other Request","Delete Record","Edit");
   $qry = $this->db->get('booking');
   foreach ($qry->result() as $row) {
$this->table->add_row($row->name,$row->nationality,$row->number_of_guest,$row->date,$row->package,$row->request,anchor('site/delete/'.$row->id, 'Del'),anchor('site/update/'.$row->id, 'edit'));

  }
   echo $this->table->generate();
```

Comment: You should be using CodeIgniter form validation.

Answer (score 0):

In codeignitor, you can update any record by giving a reference to an existing record in the table.

```
$this->db->update('booking', $booking);
```

`booking` should be the table you want to update and `$booking` must be an array with key/value pair of field name and values.

check if the table's (`booking`) field names are same as keys in `$booking`!!

Comment: i dont get it..can you specify in my code where i should edit??im really new so yeah..

Comment: In your site model code, please print the booking array (`$booking`) and check if the key names in array `$booking` is same as field names of table `booking` in database.

example: is `number_of_guest` in `$booking` is exactly `number_of_guest` in DB. match strings?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try in this way.

```
function update()
{
    $booking=array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'nationality'=>$this->input->post('nationality'),
        'number_of_guest'=>$this->input->post('number_of_guest'),
        'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),
        'package'=>$this->input->post('package'),
        'request'=>$this->input->post('request')
        );

    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->update('booking', $booking);
}
```

--------- update---

```
`    function update()
     {
        $booking=array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'nationality'=>$this->input->post('nationality'),
        'number_of_guest'=>$this->input->post('number_of_guest'),
        'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),
        'package'=>$this->input->post('package'),
        'request'=>$this->input->post('request')
        );    
    $this->db->where('<primary_key>', <pri_key_value>);
    $error =  $this->db->update('<table_name>', $booking);`,
```

Please run that and paste what you are getting in `$error`

Comment: instead of `function update()
{
    $booking=array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'nationality'=>$this->input->post('nationality'),
        'number_of_guest'=>$this->input->post('number_of_guest'),
        'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),
        'package'=>$this->input->post('package'),
        'request'=>$this->input->post('request')
        );

    $this->site_model->update_record($booking);`,

Answer (score 0):

try this code... This is my code,you can change according to your requirement.

View

```
<?php $id = "1" ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart("testimonials_controller/testimonials_edit/$id");?>
    <table width="500" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="130" align="left">Author: </td>
            <td><?php echo form_input($title); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="130" align="left">Content: </td>
            <td><?php echo form_textarea($content); ?></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'contentbox' );
            </script>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Model

```
function updatetestimonials($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('testimonials', $data);
    }
```

Controller

```
function testimonials_edit($id)
    {
            $this->load->helper('form');  
            $this->load->helper('html');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('testimonials_model');
            $this->data=$this->testimonials_model->general();
            $testimonials = $this->testimonials_model->get_testimonials($id);

        $this->data['title'] = 'Edit Testimonial';

        //validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Author', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contentbox', 'content', 'required|xss_clean');
        if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
        {       

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
            {
                $data = array(
                'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
                'content'=> $this->input->post('contentbox'),
            );

                $this->testimonials_model->updatetestimonials($id, $data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Testimonial is updated successfully.</p>");

                redirect('testimonials_controller/testimonials_edit/'.$id);
            }           
        }

        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));

        $this->data['testimonials'] = $testimonials;

        //display the edit product form


        $this->data['title'] = array(
            'name'      => 'title',
            'id'        => 'title',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('title', $testimonials['title']),
        );

        $this->data['content'] = array(
                'name'      => 'contentbox',
                'id'        => 'contentbox',
                'type'      => 'text',
                'cols'      =>  60,
                'rows'      =>  5,
                'style'     => 'width:250px;',
                'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('contentbox',$testimonials['content']),
        );

        $this->load->view('testimonials_edit', $this->data);
    }
```